# Python Boost PEP 484 style Type Hinting

Tags: boost, boost-python, typing

I want to enable type hints for my C++ code in Python.

```
using boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)
{
  docstring_options doc_options;
  doc_options.disable_all();
  doc_options.enable_user_defined();

  class_<Bar>("Bar", init<>(), "Bar class" )
    .def("foobar", &Bar::foobar, (arg("name")), "foobar(name: str) -> None");
}
```

But in python, I only get this with the type hints missing. Is there any way to keep the type hints?

```py
class Bar(__Boost_Python.instance):
    """
    Bar class
    """
    def foobar(self, name): # real signature unknown; restored from __doc__
        """
        foobar(name: str) -> None
        """
        pass
```

Comment: If I may ask: how did you get the resulting python code ? Has boost-python somehow generated it for you, or is it you that wrote it manually from the observations you've made ?

Comment: This is just the output I see in PyCharm.